# Iframe source doesn't work

Tags: html, iframe

Why can't this link be the source of an iframe?
http://exame.abril.com.br/tecnologia/facebook/noticias/facebook-nao-tem-planos-de-voltar-a-china-diz-executivo

im using jquery
$("#frame").attr("src",source);

Comment: because you need to give us specifics?

Comment: jQuery has absolutely nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="500" height="500" src="http://exame.abril.com.br/tecnologia/facebook/noticias/facebook-nao-tem-planos-de-voltar-a-china-diz-executivo">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome yields:

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

Which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options).

Answer (score 6):

It has the [`X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) http response header, which tells the user agent to only allow the page to be loaded in a frame if its parent has the same origin.

Comment: this link is not a webpage of mine. can i change it?

Comment: @JoãoPedroJunqueiraCandido: No, you cannot. The server serving the page wishes for browsers to explicitly deny the rendering.

Comment: @João: retrieve the page. Look for the header.