# Iframe created dynamically not loading

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, append

I'm creating an iframe and when I add it to the dom it does not load the url. I actually have to right click it and hit refresh...any reason for this to happen? I'm using this code on a CWE extension for Lync, that runs on an embedded browser but it's actually IE7.

Here's the code: (the url it's fine because hitting refresh load the right page so i did not included the to get the url)

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id = "myframe";
iframe.height = "400";
iframe.width = "700";
iframe.style.border = "0";
iframe.scrolling = "no";
iframe.frameBorder = "0";
iframe.style.display = "block";
iframe.setAttribute("src", this.GetUrl(x));

main.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12327877/397872

Comment: What does `this.GetUrl(x)` return?

Comment: @rishta that answer is not related with this issue. The iframe can be loaded if I hit right click and refresh.

Comment: @MrSlayer like I wrote above that method return a url. The url is valid and can be used as an iframe..that's why I did not post that method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
frame.src = this.GetUrl(x);
```

instead of:

```
iframe.setAttribute("src", this.GetUrl(x));
```

`frame.src` is the ***property***, while `iframe.setAttribute("src", this.GetUrl(x));` sets the ***attribute***.

To avoid inconsistencies and problems with old browsers, try `appendChild` first so that the DOM is aware of its existence before setting the `src`.

```
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = "myframe";
    iframe.height = "400";
    iframe.width = "700";
    iframe.style.border = "0";
    iframe.scrolling = "no";
    iframe.frameBorder = "0";
    iframe.style.display = "block";
  //  iframe.setAttribute("src", this.GetUrl(x));

    main.appendChild(iframe);
    frame.src = this.GetUrl(x);
```

Comment: it's still happening the same issue, I have cleared the cache just to be sure too :)

Comment: @nhenrique: try `frame.document.location.href = this.GetUrl(x)`

Comment: I tried that one but it's still happening. I noticed something..if i put an alert after appending the iframe, this gets loaded the first time as expected..without the alert, the iframe does not load automatically. Something interrupting the loading process of the iframe? Never faced an issue like this before

Comment: Try experimenting with **display** CSS attribute. Append with 'display: none' and then set to default (block?).

Comment: @nhenrique: that's strange, what if you `appendChild` first and then set the `src`

Comment: that actually works! btw, do you have any idea why? thank you! update your answer so i can mark it as correct :)

Comment: @nhenrique: I'm also not sure why. This could be a browser problem. Different browsers have different behaviors.